# Finding the types of function

Tags: python, function, oop

```
def hello():
    x=1
    return
print(type(hello))
```

gives `<class 'function'>` as its output, but

```
def hello():
    x=1
    return
print(type(hello()))
```

gives `<class 'NoneType'>` as its output. Why is it so?

Comment: Might want to specify the language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined a function which is named `hello`, therefore, when you print the `type` of the variable `hello` you will that get its type is function:

```
print(type(hello))
```

Output:

```
<class 'function'>
```

However, when you print the type of `hello()` you are not printing the variable, but printing the type of what the function returns after being executed. In your definition, `hello` returns nothing, or `None`, therefore the output of printing the type of the result of executing `hello` is correctly None:

```
print(type(hello()))
```

Output:

```
<class 'None'>
```

Answer (score 0):

this because `hello` its Function type variable

`typeof()` function get variable

when you put `()` after the name of function you play the function and And it's no longer variable.

and `typeof()` function can not refer to it as a variable and can't identify it